# Invisible advert not quite invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising

See the image below:

[image]

This is in chrome, using the developer console (F12) to highlight a div that has only display:none child elements and a 0x0 image, but is being shown.

The reason I found this is because when I hovered over what I thought was blank space, I got the up/down vote advert popup:

[image]

I guess it should be either completely hidden (is padding/margin the culprit), or shown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On SO, the Careers 2.0 job ads are served by Careers and the other ads on the page are served by AdZerk. You may have noticed that the Careers 2.0 ad served in the sidebar comes in both single-height and double-height flavors. The way we coordinate that is that AdZerk serves a special snippet of HTML just like it would serve a banner ad. When the careers ad loader sees that special snippet it instructs careers to send down a large sidebar ad.

What we didn't do is remove the AdZerk div, which has the voting buttons on it.

So now we do.

Comment: +1 Ha. Don't I get assist rep!? ;)

Comment: @nickhar: You can have a comment upvote!

Comment: @nickhar +1 towards your [Pundit badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit)!